# How do I use var() inside of calc()?

Tags: css, css-variables, calc

I am trying the following, in order to have the header's height subtracted from the element below it.

```
header {
  height: var(--header-height);

  --header-height: 150px;
}

main {
  height: calc(100% - var(--header-height));
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Why isn't it calculating the "150px" value inside the calc()?

Comment: Because it doesn't. It displays the "property" you set which is the variable. Are you saying that this calc doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, the issue was that the calc() didn't load the variable I wanted to use in the equation. But when I moved the declaration of the variable to :root{}, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the declaration of the variable to this:

```
:root {
  --header-height: 200px;
}
```

Now it works!

Comment: it's all about scope, without your HTML we cannot answer